# Not able to click on bootstrap modal on firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I made a "bug report" modal for my site and in the modal was not clickable at all, I searched everywhere and eventually found that the problem was the position:fixed

I added

```
transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
z-index:1000;
```

to the .modal css and it worked for chrome, but latter on i tested in firefox and there it still isn't working, i tried z-index value and other possible solutions but none worked, the only thing that works is to change the .modal position to relative, but then the modal messes up with other elements on the page.

Someone Knows how to solve this? PLEASE HELP!

CODE:

```
   .modal {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 1000;
     display: none;
     overflow: hidden;
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
     transform: translateZ(0);
     -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
     outline: 0;
   }

  .modal-backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #000;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Works on chrome and not in Firefox is Expected as far as your code is concerned. `-webkit-` styles apply only to webkit browsers (browsers like Chrome and Safar). For Firefox you should additionally add whatever the styles you added for `-webkit-` as `-moz-`. So you should append the following styles with `-moz` which will finally look like,

```
 .modal {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 1000;
     display: none;
     overflow: hidden;
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
     -moz-overflow-scrolling: touch;
     transform: translateZ(0);
     -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
     -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
     outline: 0;
   }

  .modal-backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #000;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
   }
```